# Comparing two arrays of objects and replacing values

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop, e-commerce

I have 2 arrays of objects in a e-commerce project (built in Code Igniter), one an array of product objects and one an array of sale item objects, with product id's and the amount of discount. I need to compare the arrays so I can put a new price in the items which are on sale, but I cannot seem to code the loops properly. Here is my current code:

```
private function checkSalesProducts($query) {  //$query is an array of product objects 

    $this->db->select("sale_product, sale_discount");
    $salesItems = $this->db->get("sale_items");

    foreach($salesItems->result() as $salesItem)
    {

        for($i=0; sizeof($query); ++$i)
        {

            if($salesItem->sales_product == $query[$i]->prod_id)
            {

                $query[$i]->prod_price = $query[$i]->prod_price * (1 - $salesItem->sales_discount);
                $query[$i]->sale_item = true;
                break;

            }

        }

    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($query);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The double loop results in a n*n calculation. But, I consider it is not your main issue. I don't know code igniter, are you sure `$salesItem->sales_product` is a product ID or a product? And is your code is working or just a question to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for()` should be

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($query); $i++)
```

Your script should freeze at the moment since you tell it to loop while `sizeof($query) > 0`, which it always have since you don't modify it in the loop.

Comment: That was it :) I think it was just a case of a fresh pair of eyes needed lol